# "Basic authentication" in Edge browser

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, microsoft-edge

"Basic authentication" in Edge browser doesn't have an option to save the password.
When the browser closes and reopens, the user has to re-enter the password.

Does anyone have any fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still there and it's still working, they just removed the checkbox from those dialog windows (from both Microsoft Edge as well as Microsoft Internet Explorer), making adding new credentials a bit more complicated.

The basics behind the scenes are still the same and it's indeed possible to still add those credentials so you don't have to enter them again (i.e. restore the old behavior):

- Open the classic **Control Panel**.
- Click on **User Accounts**.
- Click on **Credential Manager**.
- Pick the right tab, **Windows Credentials**

Here you'll find three lists of passwords. What you'll want is the third/bottom one: On the right side there's a link to add new credentials, click it.

As address, write down the domain name, e.g. `example.com`. You might also add a port, e.g. `example.com:443` to prevent the credentials from being sent over unsecure connections by accident (see the link in Patrick's answer). The username/password field are obvious of course.

Comment: This solution is not working with unsecure connections.

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox to save the credentials will appear in Edge if you put the site in the Trusted sites zone.

Comment: While that maybe true, the checkbox is ignored.  The root of the problem is that regardless, credentials are not saved.

Comment: When I try this now, the checkbox is not ignored. The credentials are indeed saved just like in any other browser. I have also told a few of my clients (who are using Edge and had this problem with a certain part of our web site) to do like this, and I think they were helped. One of them even confirmed that it helped him.

Comment: Works for me too - the checkbox is not ignored.